# php-login project (minimal) database connection issue

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm attempting to create a PHP-login by using this site and its accompanying source code:

[PHP Login (minimal)](https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal)

[Github source code](https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal)

I've attempted to follow the steps dictated here:

[www.dev-metal.com/how-to-install-php-login-minimal-on-windows-7-8/](http://www.dev-metal.com/how-to-install-php-login-minimal-on-windows-7-8/)

My problem starts once I attempt to login. I've looked at the config/db.php file which contains the user/pass and have attempted to use this. I've also attempted to register a user. Both have failed due to a "database connection problem".

[image: i.imgur.com/A3C6jg5.png]

I've attempted to resolve this issue by researching what can cause database connection issues, but I haven't been very successful. Thanks for the help in advance.

Error Log:

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk1Mn.jpg)

Comment: Show us the server error log?

Comment: Confirm that mysql is running, and that you've set the username and password correctly in the code.

Comment: How do I check the server error log? Also, mysql56 is running and the UN/PW is correct.

Comment: I've added the server error log to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have no active mysqli. Check if in php.ini you have this line:

;extension=php_mysqli.dll (with or without ;)

if the line begin with ";" remove it and restart apache. Then try again.

The php.ini file is located inside apache or php folder.

EDIT: The problem at the end is because a bad configuration of db.php (see comments)